# Where are the files necessary to modify when adding a system call to linux-2.6.31

Tags: linux-kernel, version, system-calls, unistd.h

when i search for adding a system call, i get many articles but they seem to be for old versions, it also seems like a trivial process.

But the problem is, the directories that articles suggest does not hold for the version 2.6.31. does anyone know where `unistd.h`, `syscall_table.S` and `syscalls.h` or their corresponding files are?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for `unistd.h : $SOURCE_PATH/arch/x86/include/asm/unistd_32.h`

for `syscalls.h : $SOURCE_PATH/arch/x86/include/asm/syscalls.h`

for `syscall_table_32.h : $SOURCE_PATH/arch/x86/kernel/syscall_table_32.h`

obviously i'm on x86 machine.

Answer (score 0):

On most Linux systems such header files can be found under:

> /usr/src/kernels/$KERNEL-VERSION/include/linux/

You need to have your kernel sources installed to be able to do any kernel development though, if that's what're trying to do, since `unistd.h` is part of the standard gcc library as well.

Comment: Now, i downloaded source of 2.6.31 and extracted it. i want to add a system call to this source then build and install it. What you're saying is that this is impossible? else, inside this source, where is those files, i found unistd.h and syscalls.h there. Are those the ones to modify?

Comment: You'd do a lot better is you download the sources as a distro package, make the modifications and rebuild the packages. Building and installing a custom kernel from vanilla sources is not always a good idea, especially if you're not very familiar with the underlying distribution. I've worked as a kernel developer for time so I should know :-)